# R Download ZIP with RCURL and log in

Tags: r, web-scraping, rcurl

I am trying to log in to a website("dkurl") below and then download a zip file("url") below.  Following other answers using RCURL, I have attempted to use the code below, however I cannot get the file downloaded.  Are there other parameters or commands I am missing?

```
url <- 'http://www.draftkings.com/contest/exportfullstandingscsv/40827113'
dkurl <- 'https://www.draftkings.com/account/sitelogin/'
pars = list(username = xxx, password = xxx)
agent = "Mozilla/5.0"
curl = getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(cookiejar="", useragent = agent, followlocation = TRUE, curl=curl)
html=postForm(dkurl, .params=pars, curl=curl)
html=getURL(url, curl=curl)
```

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure this out? I'm facing a similar issue ...

Answer (score 1):

It's quite convenient to download files using `httr` package. Just like this.

```
library(httr)
GET(fileUrl, authenticate(user, password), 
    write_disk(filename), timeout(60))
```